# Mysql: Line breaks shown as squares in table

Tags: mysql

Any solution for this? How to get rid of squares in mysql?

It's `\n` or `\r` as i understand, but why they are looking like squares in mysql?

Thanks ;)

Comment: How do you display the content? PHP? Ruby? Swing? HTML? .net?

Comment: `\r` is a carriage-return sybol. `\n` is a line-breaking one. in Win they gather to form a 'newline' faction =)

Comment: Encoding is UTF-8. All symbols are ok. Just line breaks. I'm displaying data via HeidiSQL

Comment: Sounds like encoding issue to me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do two thing to get rid to squares in MySQL storage, either replace the backslash with double backslash e.g. \n = \n which will force to write \n in MySQL database. Another is while entering data you have to add mysql_real_escape_string() function while storing data.